# How to connect my mobile wallet to a full node via a TOR hidden service address?

Tags: wallet, full-node, tor, mobile

I would like to configure a mobile (Android) wallet to connect to a TOR-enabled full node (Bitcoin Core), via its onion address. I haven't decided which wallet to use yet. It will depend, of course, on the answer to this question :)

Is it possible to do this? I realize I would need to keep the onion address static, or at least reconfigure my wallet if it changes. Also, I assume I'd need some kind of Android TOR application...

If I can't do it using TOR, I understand that the standard method is to install an Electrum Server on the full node, then use a compatible wallet to connect to it. This may be old information, however. I have also seen some wallets that can connect directly to a full node by IP address. I'd rather not set up port forwarding on that router if there is a better way.

A few wallets claim TOR support (Sparrow, Wasabi, Mycelium, etc), but I believe these are all desktop wallets without an Android version.

My research is confounded by the difficulty of knowing which web resources are out of date and which are current.

So, as of now (early 2023), what are some good methods to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I make the assumption that you have already gone through the steps of installing a bitcoin node that operate, exclusively or not, on the tor network.
Here is a resume of a proposed solution :
You have to install first the tor bundle if not yet.
So as to the remote connection to this node by onion service, you can set up an electrum server on your local machine, and create a hidden service (see in /etc/tor/torrc) to instruct your system so that it will pass the incoming connections on the tor proxy to the working port of your electrum server (default 50001).
Don't forget to open port 50001 if you have a running firewall on your bitocin server. But don't worry about opening a specific port on your router in ths case, because tor proxy service don't need that (remind the term 'hidden').
If you want much of a complete installation, you can set up a reverse proxy server such as nginx over your electrum server. On the outside of your server it will exchange paquets with on ssl mode, and transmit them securely on the localhost to  electrum server. Create a hidden service for this proxy server too, and you'll be able to remote connect your node on your server over tor service, via port 50001 (no ssl but tor's already encrypted) or 50002 (tor over ssl encryption, at your choice. And you need to open neither 50001 nor 50002 port on your router.
Lastly, install electrum mobile wallet + Orbot (some type of tor bundle for androïd) on your mobile phone to enable electrum wallet (and other apps) to connect through tor.
For tips on the server set up :
[setting up electrum server](https://youtu.be/mbG7hBMWQrs?list=PLmoQ11MXEmaiEJotCM7sq86exsBQWVkT0)
[setting up proxy server nginx](https://youtu.be/IbOxgdHsyRI?list=PLmoQ11MXEmaiEJotCM7sq86exsBQWVkT0)